# Dynamically generated table binding with smarttable UI5

Tags: sapui5, hana

I have a requirement where HANA tables are generated dynamically and I need to bind them with smart table in UI5.

Could you please suggest how to achieve this functionality?

Normally we would mentioned the table in XSodata file but here tables are generated dynamically, hence not sure of how to do